# Dynamically creating member pages

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to website creation and I am using login/membership features. How would I dynamically create a new, permanent web page (profile page) for a member once they sign up?

```
//where I would use the code


//Javascript
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
     // User is signed in.
     //Navigate to the User's page, which does not yet exist
     var url = "http://example.com/" + user.uid;
     window.location = url;



   } else {
// No user is signed in.
}
});
```

Comment: Are you using a CMS, or writing this from scratch? What code (or thought process) have you attempted thus far that we can look at?

Comment: I am writing this from scratch. I am using Firebase as my back-end and have only implemented very simple /sign up code.

Comment: It's helpful if you can provide more information. Where have you got to so far with your code?

Comment: @Joundill  I added it in

Comment: @CalebAnthony I added it in, its not much but I hope it helps you get anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the docs.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile

I suggest having a read of some FireBase documentation, you'll likely need to find out about how FireBase routing works (assuming you're using it as a server)

However, for your requirements (i.e. a user profile page), you can just grab the data and display it at a general profile URL.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, email, photoUrl, uid;

if (user != null) {
  name = user.displayName;
  email = user.email;
  photoUrl = user.photoURL;
  uid = user.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
                   // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
                   // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
}
```